# How to enable paypal pro for country SG in Magento 1.8.1?

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I’m using Magento 1.8.1 and am attempting to use Website Payments Pro system.I want to enable Pay-pal Pro for Singapore country but cant access pay-pal pro on Singapore

Please help me if any one have any idea how to enable pay-pal pro for SG(Singapore) country

Thanks Advance !

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Payments Pro is only available for merchants based in the US, UK or Canada.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/howto_product_matrix/